# Find matrix A so that it is a is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find the matrix $A$ if

$$\begin{pmatrix}2& 1\\ 3& 2 \\  \end{pmatrix} A \begin{pmatrix}-3&2\\5&-3 \\  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1& 0\\ 0& 1 \\  \end{pmatrix}$$

Using the inverse of a $2\times 2$ matrix.

Comment: Your table (matrix) is not showing up as it looks like HTML. Can you type the question without HTML or use MathJax?

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I extracted your html and you don't have any numbers entered. I suggest you just indent your matrix lines by four spaces and use fixed-width positioning, if that is appropriate. Also describe the issue in words; this will be helpful in any case for good answers.

Comment: I edited the question, please help..

Comment: @Amsar Now that you've edited the question, what have you tried to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

**Sketch:** You have the equation $C\cdot A\cdot B=I$. Since $C$ and $B$ must be (and they are indeed) invertible, the way to go is $$A=C^{-1}(CAB)B^{-1}=C^{-1}IB^{-1}=C^{-1}B^{-1}$$